# Delete song, lyrics, and poetry tags

Tags: support, tags

The author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432031/do-these-lyrics-have-meaning) (now deleted) managed to not only ask the most off-topic question I've yet seen but also tag it with [song](/questions/tagged/song), [lyrics](/questions/tagged/lyrics) and [poetry](/questions/tagged/poetry). They have a couple of questions each but they seem to describe just application features or data content. Remove?

Comment: Ah ahaha hahahahahaha. Incredible.

Comment: I can imagine a question like "How can I write a song as Perl code?" for which all those tags would be useful.

Answer (score 8):

They certainly don't promote on-topic questions for sure or are just extraneous tags.  Used mostly in a very localized manner (e.g., "I want to get the lyrics of a song so I can do poetry, how do I get that (in <langage>)?").

I went through and removed the tags [song](/questions/tagged/song), [lyrics](/questions/tagged/lyrics) and [poetry](/questions/tagged/poetry) on all questions that have them applied.

*A lot* of those questions were also close candidates as well.  Search my [editing history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado?tab=activity&sort=revisions) if you guys with closing/deleting abilities want to see these posts and add to my votes.

Comment: I also want to bring attention to the tag: [tag:follow].  Just a "tag fragment" that people seem to be using the create sentences with or used in the context of social media to "follow" someone, doesn't seem like a good standalone tag.

Comment: I burninated follow

Comment: Sweet.​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Jeff: But, where's the fancy image? I demand the fancy image!